# Adding $ Symbol to Jquery Mobile Slider

Tags: jquery, mobile, input, slider, currency

How could I add the currency symbol to the input field in Jquery Mobile Slider?
I don't want to have it in a label.

I'm using the jquery mobile slider http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/slider

And the HTML code is:

```
<form>
 <div class="ui-slider">
  <input name="slider-s" id="slider-s" value="125000" min="0" max="1500000" data-highlight="true" type="range" data-icon="search">
 </div>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try being a bit more specific on what you have (e.g. code) and what you want to happen, to get a better answer-

Comment: Hi Nick,

I'm using the jquery mobile slider
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/slider/

And the HTML code is:
<form>
   <div class="ui-slider"> 
      <input name="slider-s" id="slider-s" value="125000" min="0" max="1500000" data-highlight="true" type="range" data-icon="search">                   
   </div>
</form>

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

can you please used this below code :

HTML CODE :

```
<div class="dollar">
    <input type="text" value="12" name="thresholdSelect" >
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.dollar:after {
    content: "$"
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/malvaniya_shakti/Tt2hU/16/)